# Getting a 'ReflectionException' error, "Class modules\Module does not exist' when I change the namespace of my module in Craft 3

Tags: modules

First attempt at making a module. So far all I've done is try to change the namespace of the template that was included with my freshly installed craft 3.0.23.1 project.

Was following the official docs (https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html#set-up-the-basic-file-structure) and spend a few hours trying to figure this out on various searches here and elsewhere.

So in the file '/modules/Module.php' I changed

```
namespace modules;
```

to

```
namespace banana\modules;
```

, then in '/composer.json' changed:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
```

to

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "banana\\modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
```

Then in Terminal, ran the command 'composer dump-autoload -a' in the project folder. Reload the page and I get the error. Other than just doing the setup wizard, i haven't touched any other files in the project.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit difficult without seeing all of your code, but I'm going to guess that you also need to make changes in your `config/app.php` to make the namespace changes you're making.

So two things I'd recommend... first, you can generate your module's framework here: https://pluginfactory.io/

...and second I wrote up a tutorial on creating a module in the [Enhancing a Craft CMS 3 Website with a Custom Module](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module) article.

Comment: Ah, the problem was when i set the Module ID in 'config/app.php'. I thought the value of the 'class' key was using the path to the class file. But I see it's actually  '{namespace}\{class name}::class'. 

Thanks @andrew.welch for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I added it to the config/app.php file, as well as the composer.json and forgot to run composer update

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself recently. It turned out to be a autoloader problem. I had forgotten to run composer dump-autoload on my project directory. I generally don't bother editing the composer autoload file manually.